# Java GUI to accept only certain names

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm currently working on a GUI where you enter your name and it tells you whether or not it has been accepted. Say that if the names "John" or "Jane" are entered then you get a "Verified" message or "Unverified" message if you type any other name. Here's what I have so far, just really unsure how to add the IF statement for detecting the certain names. Thanks.

**NamePrompt.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class NamePrompt extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String name;

    public NamePrompt(){

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel enterYourName = new JLabel("Enter Your Name Here:");
        JTextField textBoxToEnterName = new JTextField(21);
        JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
        panelTop.add(enterYourName);
        panelTop.add(textBoxToEnterName);

        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.addActionListener(new SubmitButton(textBoxToEnterName));
        JPanel panelBottom = new JPanel();
        panelBottom.add(submit);

        //Add panelTop to JFrame
        add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //JFrame set-up
        setTitle("Name Prompt Program");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NamePrompt promptForName = new NamePrompt();
        promptForName.setVisible(true); 
    }

}
```

**SubmitButton.java**

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class SubmitButton implements ActionListener {

    JTextField nameInput;

    public SubmitButton(JTextField textfield){
        nameInput = textfield;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent submitClicked) {
        Component frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame , "You've Submitted the name " + nameInput.getText() + " which is allowed.");
    }


}
```

Comment: Does capitalization matter? How many names do you anticipate needing to check and is it a list that could grow?

Comment: Sorry, should've specified this but it's been covered below. lower/uppercase doesn't matter. There's two names (the admins) and that isn't growing from two at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `actionPerformed` method is called after clicking the submit button.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent submitClicked) {
    Component frame = new JFrame();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame , "You've Submitted the name " + nameInput.getText() + " which is allowed.");

    // You can store the value of whatever the user enters.
    String inputName = nameInput.getText();

    // And add the if statements:
    if(inputName.equals("John") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Verified");
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can create a List of Strings that contains all the names that is accepted. Example:

```
List<String> acceptedNames = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"John", "Jane"});
// and check
if acceptedNames.contains(inputName) {
    // verified.
}
```

Comment: per comments the name is case insensitive so this solution won't work for names like JOHN or john even though it should!

Comment: OP didn't include case insensivity, which is why I didn't include it in the answer either.

@AliBoulala You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in another answer, this should be handled in the actionPerformed method.  However, going based on what you've presented to the community, here's something that should work;

if the names are case sensitive, your modification would be as such:

```
public SubmitButton(JTextField textfield){
    nameInput = textfield;
    if (nameInput.equals("InsertCaseSensitiveName")) {
        //TODO: Verified Name
    } else {
        //TODO: Unverified Name
    }
}
```

if case insensitive:

```
public SubmitButton(JTextField textfield){
    nameInput = textfield;
    if (nameInput.equalsIgnoreCase("InsertCaseSensitiveName")) {
        //TODO: Verified Name
    } else {
        //TODO: Unverified Name
    }
}
```

To use a list:

```
//initialize your list (formed so backwards compatible)
List<String> valid = new java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
//Within a function, add all names to the list in lowercase (java.lang.String.toLowerCase())

    public SubmitButton(JTextField textfield){
        nameInput = textfield;
        if (valid.contains(nameInput.toLowerCase()) {
            //TODO: Verified Name
        } else {
            //TODO: Unverified Name
        }
    }
```

References:

[conditional if statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

[java.lang.String.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

[java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))

[java.lang.String.toLowerCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase())

[java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

[java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Comment: Thanks a million for the help Wayne. I got it working!